# How to get MAX(column) value to float or double in SQLite Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, max

I want to get the max value of a column as float or double, but I can't get it to work. It works fine with integers.

```
//this is OK
if(cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0)
{
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return (Integer) cursor.getInt(0);
}
//this does NOT work
if(cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0)
{
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return (Double) cursor.getDouble(0);
}
```

I've tried the same for SUM() and it works fine with Long, Integer, Double and Float. I don't know why it doesn't with MAX.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What is the type of that column in database?

Comment: It's returning an Infinity value, does anyone know why that happens?

Comment: andrew, it's a REAL column. That is why I want to get the MAX as float or double.

Comment: the double is returning as an infinity? The integer?

Comment: Sorry the Float and the Double return Infinity from MAX(real_column), Integer and Long work ok (tested Integer and Long in INTEGER column, not the REAL column)

Comment: that`s sound interesting. What`s the value when you return a long? I think you should avoid to cast to Double object. it should be return (double) cursor.getDouble(0);

Comment: Check the value of that real_column in the database. What should it return? What is stored there? Also post your queries.

Comment: I've tried Double and double, Float and float and it doesn't make a difference. The integer and long methods return the correct max value, so the  assertion is successful. Also, to make it better, MIN works fine, it's only on MAX (using the same table, same column, same rows)

Comment: I create the same data every time, before running the test, so it always is the same number of rows and the same values in each row.

Comment: These are the queries (from the logcat) which I execute with rawQuery:
SQL Statement: SELECT MAX(NUM_EMPLOYEES) FROM DEPARTMENTS; //Int and Long, both work fine
SQL Statement: SELECT MAX(BUDGET) FROM DEPARTMENTS; //Double and float, both return Infinity
on the other hand
SQL Statement: SELECT MIN(BUDGET) FROM DEPARTMENTS; //Double and float, both return the correct value!!!

Comment: Also, if the cursor is NULL, it returns a negative value and in this case it's returning Infinity, so I can't see the problem with the query or the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

Found it! Thanks to andrew suggestion, I check the data that was actually being saved in the database. I was dividing one of the values by 0 in one of the iterations of the loop I use to create the test data. So the Infinity value was being saved in the database. The query and the cursor were allright all along. Thanks for the help!